Can the discriminant of a polynomial with symbolic exponent be used when the exponent is real valued?
If I am not mistaken, the discriminant of $f(x) = x^{n} -bx+c$ is $$ n^{n }c^{ n-1}-(n-1)^{n-1 }b^{n }.$$ If $n$ is integer the discriminant is zero when the multiplicity of a root is at least two. Is that also true if $n$ is real ?

If $n$ is real but not an (non-negative) integer, then $f(x)$ is not a polynomial.

@CalvinLin yes, but I am not sure which part of my question might lead the reader to think that I am considering $f$ to be a polynomial. I am asking because $f$ would not be a polynomial and so I can not directly apply the discriminant without justifying why I can.

Does the idea of discriminants exists for non-polynomials? If yes, what is the discriminant of (say) $e^x$, $ \sin x$ or $ \sqrt{x}$?
